# $2^4 = 4^2$ are there any other solutions to $x^y = y^x$?

Tags: calculus, logarithms

How would I go about solving $x^y = y^x$?

$$\frac{y}{\ln y} = \frac{x}{\ln x} $$

Is trivial to find, but I'm not sure where I'd go from here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you after integer solutions? Or real solutions?

Comment: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/67256.html never mind.
I was looking for integer solutions

Comment: Try drawing a plot of $f(x) = \frac{x}{log(x)}$

Comment: Dear @FrancisTP, I think it would be quite alright to post the contents of that link as an answer yourself and accept the answer.

Comment: Of course, there is always the pair $(x,y)=(1.1)$.

Comment: Any $x=y$ except $0$ is a solution as well.  That is all in the integers.

Comment: But the only non-trivial integer pair is $(2/4)$, but there are more rational non-trivial solutions.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2013607/find-all-positive-integers-such-that-xy-yx?noredirect=1&lq=1) is related

Answer (score 0):

The plot of $\frac{\ln x}{x}$ looks so:

[image]

By searching for the solutions of $\frac{x}{\ln x} = \frac{y}{ln y}$ where $x \ne y$, you are looking for the points of this plot with the same $y$-coordinate.

As you can see, $2^4 = 4^2$ is your only integer solution.

Answer (score 0):

Plotting (using Geogebra) $\frac{x}{\log_{10}(x)}=\frac{y}{\log_{10}(y)}$ gives

[image]

As we can see, the only integral solutions are $(2,4)$ and $(4,2)$ (as well as the trivial $(x,x) \in \Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z}$ solutions). This is because as $y$ (respectively $x$) increases, the curve asymptotes to an $x$ coordinate of $>1$ (respectively $y$ coordinate of $>1$) but never reaches it.

Comment: Don't forget the solution -2, -4.

Answer (score 0):

The only integer solution is (2,4).

You are solving

$$y^x=x^y$$

and if you fix $y$, you (almost) always have two solutions for $x$. One is $x=y$, the other is not expressible in closed form with "traditional"  functions, but you can use the transcendental function $W(z)$, the Lambert function, which solves

$$xe^x=z \mapsto x=W(z)$$

To do this, you transform the equation into

$$e^{x\ln y}x^{-y}=1$$
$$x e^{(-x\ln y/y)}=1$$
$$(-x\ln y/y) e^{(-x\ln y/y)}=-\ln y/y$$

The parenthesised expression can be your unknown, arriving at

$$-\frac{x\ln y}{y}=W(-\ln y/y)$$

$$x=-\frac{y}{\ln y}W(-\ln y/y)$$

Provided you have a way to compute $W$, this gives you a solution.

Special case: for $y=e$, the only (double) solution is $x=y=e$. This is the crossover point: for $y<e$, the nontrivial solution is $x>e$ and vice-versa.